# Setting wp_temp_dir and permissions not working for "Missing A Temporary Folder" error

Tags: uploads, media, filesystem, wp-filesystem

I have a problem uploading files to my main webpress site (e.g. [www.main.com](http://www.main.com)) and all the other pages that live in it (e.g. [www.main.com/anotherpage](http://www.main.com/anotherpage)). I know there is a method to set a temp folder like

`define( 'WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/temp/' );`

but I have already put this line in the `wp-config.php` file but I did have any success. Also I have already changed all permissions to the folders using (maybe is better to use 775, but I wanted to check if that could help)

`sudo chmod 777 /wp-content/temp`

But I did not have any success either. I am not really sure where this problem came from; maybe after a plugin update.
I am pretty new in wordpress and I'm not sure how to proceed. I hope someone can give a hint with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question mentions the permissions but says nothing about ownership. Telling me I have full read write execute access to my own house doesn't mean my neighbour now has that access too, the group and user who own the files and folders matters. I'm also not sure what temporary folders has to do with uploads, there's no information about the problems with uploading, where are you seeing the error? What's the exact error message? _Have you contacted your host?_

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error message is "Missing a temporary folder" when I try to upload a file to wordpress, The problem came maybe after the plugins were updated, Regarding to the group this is the information of my user `servcom:x:1001:apache`. The host is a server inside my university and I have not had contact with them. Thanks for your help I am a bit disoriented right now.

Comment: then you should disable all plugins until the problem goes away which will identify the plugin that updated and caused the problem. Plugins can interfere with the upload process to try and do things, and they aren't always built correctly. Or you can revert to a backup

Comment: oh,  just a silly question: do you know if its possible to "lose" the ownership of the files?. This because when I run this 
`$user = getenv('APACHE_RUN_USER');
$group = getenv('APACHE_RUN_GROUP');`
the result is null. 
And running this 
`echo phpinfo();`
the result is : `User/Group  apache(48)/48`

Comment: oh, and the "Export media with selected content" plugin was used to export data from the main domain to a subdomain bit now the plugin has been disabled. But the problem is in all subdomains even in the ones where the pluging was not installed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wp\_temp\_dir does not change the /tmp temporary default directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/402799/wp-temp-dir-does-not-change-the-tmp-temporary-default-directory)