# wp_temp_dir does not change the /tmp temporary default directory

Tags: uploads, media, filesystem

I have a problem changing the temporary folder. I have have define the new temporary folder using

`define( 'WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/temp/' );`

before the line

`/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */`

but without any success. I have created a small `test.php` script to checking the success of changing to the new temporary folder such that

`<?php echo sys_get_temp_dir() . PHP_EOL; ?>`

with the output

`/tmp`

I have checked the permissions of the `wp-config.php`, `wp-content/temp/` and `wp-includes/functions.php` files and they are the equivalent to 777.

I am not sure how to proceed and I have not found a lot information on internet. I hope someone could give me a hint. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys_get_temp_dir` is not a WordPress function, [it's a core PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php). It cannot be modified or changed using WordPress constants. To modify this would require changes to the servers operating system by the `root` user.

Instead, `WP_TEMP_DIR` can be used to influence the value of `get_temp_dir` which is a WordPress function.

> In the event that this function does not find a writable location, It may be overridden by the `WP_TEMP_DIR` constant in your `wp-config.php` file.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_temp_dir/

`WP_TEMP_DIR` gives you the opportunity to set up a temporary folder WordPress can use if it cannot find a system folder to do it. Perhaps because you are on a server that has been misconfigured, or perhaps `systemd` has been configured with `PrivateTmp=true` preventing `/tmp` from being used.

`get_temp_dir` is used when generating files for download, or for setting constants for 3rd party libraries.

I'm not sure what the problem is that you hoped to solve by changing the returned value of `sys_get_temp_dir`, but `WP_TEMP_DIR` is not the solution you hoped it to be, and does not do what you thought it did. You should create a question asking how to solve your original problem.

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply. I am pretty new editing wordpress files and I had, and still have, misconceptions between wordpress and php. The problem that I have it that I can not solve the "Missing temporary folder" problem. This is the questions related to the problem. 

[link] (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/402763/setting-wp-temp-dir-and-permissions-not-working-for-missing-a-temporary-folder)

I really apreciate all your help,

Comment: I see. In the meantime if this answered your question can you consider marking it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Sure! Thanks for your help!